# How do I sync recorded voice to animation on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, voice-recording

I want to record voice and sync that up with animation on the iphone as a user touches the screen.  Are there apis that will help me accomplish this?  I've not done anything like this so I"m having a hard time visualizing the type of algorithm that would help me accomplish this.

Comment: ,i am also looking for same solution .If you get any idea please post it .Thanking you Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by saving [recorder currentTime] and then using an animation loop on playback in a different thread that polls the player and animates based on these saved times.  You can poll the player using [player currentTime] as well.